# dcAccordian issue on expand collapse in wordpress

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress

hi there i am using dcAccordion jquery file for my plugin menu. I add a attribute for collapse and expand int he file and make a condition for it and use plus(+) minus(-) sign for it.

When i first time open the site the sign is showing me at the parent menu, now if i click the parent menu the plus sign converts into minus sign but when i click on the child menu the minus sign turned into plus sign again. don't know what is happening.

Here is my code:

Collapse/expand attribute in dcAccordion file

```
expandCollaps: true
```

Here is my condition

```
// Here is my condition
if (defaults.expandCollaps == true) {
    $('li.' + classParentLi, obj).each(function() {
    var state = {
    collapse: '<span class="wpc-collapse"> (-)<span>',
    expand: '<span class="wpc-expand"> (+)</span>'
}
$(this).find('a').first().append(state.expand);
$(this).click(function() {
if ($(this).find('span').hasClass('wpc-collapse')) {
    $(this).find('span').remove();
    $(this).find('a').first().append(state.expand);
 } else {
     $(this).find('span').remove();
     $(this).find('a').first().append(state.collapse);
  }
});


});
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I add this code in my plugin main page

```
<?php
function wpc_accordiaon() {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            jQuery('.wpc-categories li a.active').find('.wpc-expand').toggleClass('wpc-collapse');
        })
    </script>
<?php
}
?>
```

And my dcAccordion work perfectly